# Durovis and Unity trouble

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gyroscope, google-cardboard, durovis-dive

I'm using Unity 4.6.1 
I was trying to integrate the dive camera to my project. When I render , it works fine and I'm able to emulate head movements with my mouse.
However, when building and porting it to android I get no response with movements.

Is it some setting I did not change in the Dive plugin ? Or something else with Unity building ?( I did have trouble setting the path for Java ) Any alternative ? How do I troubleshoot ?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue! It worked originally but stopped working yesterday. 

Mouse emulation works. Perhaps it is an update thats removing it. I've removed every part since it last worked and its still broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely uninstalled and removed all components related to Durovis, and that worked! See this tutorial if that still doesn't work:

http://www.talkingquickly.co.uk/2014/11/google-cardboard-unity-tutorial/